# Read parquet in chunks according to ordered column index with pyarrow

Tags: dask, parquet, pyarrow

I have a dataset composed of multiple parquet files `clip1.parquet, clip2.parquet,...`. Each row corresponds to a point in some frame and there's an ordered column specifying the corresponding frame `frame: 1,1,...1,2,2,2...2,3,3...3...`. There are several thousand rows for each frame, but the exact number is not necessarily the same. Frame numbers <strike>do not</strike> reset in each clip.

What is the fastest way to iteratively read all rows belonging to one frame?

Loading the whole dataset to memory is not possible. I assume a standard row filter will check against all rows which is not optimal (I know they are ordered by frame). I was thinking it could be possible to match a row-group for each frame, but wasn't sure if it's a good practice or even possible with different sized groups.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonable in your case to consider the `frame` column as your index, and you can specify this when loading. If you scan the metadata of all the files (this is fast for local data, but not on by default), then dask will know the min and max frame values for each file. Therefore, selecting on the index will only read the files which have at least some corresponding values.

```
df = dd.read_parquet("clip*.parquet", index="frame", calculate_divisions=True)
df[df.index == 1]  # so something with this
```

Alternatively, you can specify *filters* in readparquet, if you want even more control, and you would make a new dataframe object for each iteration.

Note, however, that a groupby might do what you want, without having to iterate over the frame numbers. Dask is pretty smart about loading only part of the data at a time and aggregating partial results from each partition. How well this works depends on how complicated an algorithm you want to do to each row set.

I should mention that both parquet backend support all these options, you don't specifically need pyarrow.

Comment: I noticed a mistake in my question, the frame numbers do reset to 0 in each parquet file. Is there a way in dask to have a multi-index including both clip and frame number? or if not an easy way to change the frame numbers to be consecutive?

Comment: I do quiet heavy computation on each frame (point-cloud manipulation) and I iterate over the frames in consecutive pairs. Is using groupby efficient for iterating even when I don't parallelize over groups?

Comment: A multi-index is possible, but probably not what you want, especially if it isn't in fact sorted. A groupby generally involves many-to-many shuffles, so can be inefficient; but you should try it first.